# MySQL process showing in top but no errors logged

Tags: mysql, top

I am seeing the following in TOP

```
 2311 mysql      20   0 1324M  646M  9188 S  0.0 17.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ip-172-30-3-82.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/ip-172-30-3-82.pid
```

When I tail the error file I don't see anything new. How can I stop these (Or does it matter?)

```
tail -f /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-30-3-82.err
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.24-72.2 started; log sequence number 25825378787
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-06-08 14:20:40 2310 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.24-72.2'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release 72.2, Revision 8d0f85b
```

Comment: What errors do you expect to see?

Comment: That seems pretty normal to me also. That's what I would expect from a normally running mysql server.

Comment: My question is about pid 2311 - I am seeing 20 different instances of this

Comment: IIRC, each connection counts as a Process, i.e 19 connections and the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a process is in `top` and utilizing resources does not mean it's experiencing errors. This is expected with databases, especially with databases such as MySQL.

To see what exactly is going on with MySQL you can use `mytop` or run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` from within the `mysql` client.